# Gmap - Dynamically load markers on map pan

Tags: google-maps

How can I add new markers when the user pans the map? For example, my database contains 100,000 markers and loading them all would be unfeasible. When the user moves the map, I would want the script to issue a new call to the database to retrieve the new markers. Here is the code that I have so far:

`$url = "http://example.com/products?limit=200&offset=0&lat=40.756623&lng=-73.98487";
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        $results = json_decode($data,true);
        $markers = array();
        $test = array();
        foreach($results as $result)
        {
            if(!empty($result['lat']) && !empty($result['lon']) && !empty($result['dealTitle']))
            {
                $key = $result['lat']."_".$result['lon'];
                if(!in_array($key,$test))
                {
                    array_push($test,$key);
                }
                $temp = array("text"=>$result['dealTitle'],
                                "latitude"=>$result['lat'],
                                "longitude"=>$result['lon']);
                array_push($markers,$temp);
            }
        }`

```
    // a simple GMap array
      $map_array1 = array(
        'id' => "my-map",         // id attribute for the map
        'width' => "100%",        // map width in pixels or %
        'height' => "400px",      // map height in pixels
        'latitude' => 40.735812,    // map center latitude
        'longitude' => -74.010987,  // map center longitude
        'maptype' => "Map",       // baselayer type
        'markers' => $markers,
      );
      $element1 = array(
        '#type' => 'gmap',
        '#gmap_settings' => $map_array1,
      );
      $html = drupal_render($element1);
```

Comment: Anyone have a solution?